# How to show user-friendly field names?

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.NET form bound to a database to insert some data in a table.

The datatable of form has some columns with strange names. In the application side, I'm setting the Caption of each column in order to show a user-friendly name for each field.

When something goes wrong in inserting data, entry data are not validated and I get an error message which is normal, but my problem is that the error message I'm receiving still shows the "system" strange name of the field which causes the problem and not the caption affected.

### Example:

Field A :

- Field Name in the database : "SYS_USER_FIRST_NAME"
- Field caption shown in the form : "First Name"
- Field type : varchar(10)

When a new row is inserted, the following code adds to row to the datatable :

```
If NewAddedRow.RowState = DataRowState.Detached Then
    Try
        DataTable.Rows.Add(NewAddedRow)
    Catch Ex As Exception
        MsgBox(Ex.message)
    End Try
End If
```

Now, if I insert "**This is a long text inserted in 10-caracters field**"

I got the message :

- **Cannot set column "SYS_USER_FIRST_NAME". The value violates the MaxLenght limit of this column.**

And not :

- **Cannot set column "First Name".  The value violates the MaxLenght limit of this column.**

Does any one know how to show this user friendly field captions instead of their row names in the database ?

Comment: I typically try to add some data validation step(s) to **prevent** them from happening in the first place (for instance set the TextBox MaxLength property to 10).  With a little experience you can usually weed out 70-80% of the possible errors.  The rest of the time it really doesnt seem to matter - users rarely convey error messages but instead you get "some error" and "all this gobbledy gook" rather than anything useful